# How to show only the first row from result of a query

Tags: vb.net

In below code, I want to show data from database only in first row. How can I show data?

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM category "
Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
Dim dataset As New DataSet
adp.Fill(dataset, "Table")
For Each dbrow As DataRow In dataset.Tables("Table").Rows
    'subcate.Items.Add(dbrow.Item("sub_cate"))
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = dbrow.Item("code")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than retrieving the entire list from the database and then only showing the first row, it's more efficient to make the database do the work and only return the first row, particularly if the `categories` table has a large number of records. The actual SQL syntax might vary depending on what database you're using, but you could try something like:

```
Dim sql as string = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM category"
```

Also, consider using a `OleDbCommand` object rather than an `OleDbDataAdapter` if you're displaying the data as read-only, as there's more overhead in creating a `DataAdapter` object.

Comment: If you have a `TOP 1` - you also need an `ORDER BY` - otherwise you might be getting unpredictable results since there is no implied order in any SQL database - you **must** explicitly ask for it by having an `ORDER BY` in your statement

Comment: Yup, that would make sense.  :-)